# Error 'Cannot read property 'random_value' of undefined' of undefined en Unit Test

Tags: angular, pruebas-unitarias, karma-jasmine, jasmine

Estoy empezando a programar pruebas unitarias, aunque todavía soy un poco novato.

Y recibo el siguiente error al lanzar el código que os muestro a continuacion. He probado a reinstalar '@azure/msal-angular'; por si acaso pudiera ser el problema ese, pero no soluciono nada.

¿A que se debe el error que ahora os muestro? ¿Debo inicializar ese metodo de alguna manera como Unit Test tambien?

¿Podriais echarme una mano para encontrar el problema?

**ERROR**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUHToken' of undefined
            at getTokenAndPicture (src/app/shared/sidenav/sidenav.component.ts:31:17)
            at SidenavComponent.call [as ngOnInit] (src/app/shared/sidenav/sidenav.component.ts:56:3)
            at callHook (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:2498:22)
            at callHooks (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:2467:17)
            at executeInitAndCheckHooks (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:2418:9)
            at refreshView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:11992:21)
            at renderComponentOrTemplate (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:12094:9)
            at tickRootContext (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:13215:13)
            at detectChangesInRootView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:13241:5)
            at RootViewRef.detectChanges (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:13757:9)
```

**CODE**

**TS**

```
public ngOnInit() {

        let retries = 0;

        const retryLimit = 3;
        const getTokenAndPicture = () => {
            this.picture.getUHToken().subscribe({
                next: result => {
                    sessionStorage.setItem("token", result.accessToken);
                    this.picture.getPicture(sessionStorage.getItem("token"), this.userService.enterpriseId).subscribe(
                        response => {
                            if (response) {
                                this.profile = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + response;
                                this.isImgProfileLoaded = true;
                            }
                        },
                        error => {
                            if (error.status === 401) {
                                if (retries < retryLimit) {
                                    retries++;
                                    getTokenAndPicture();
                                } else {
                                    console.log("Maximum retry limit reached.");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
        };

        getTokenAndPicture();
```

**SPEC**

```
describe('SidenavComponent', () => {
    let component: SidenavComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<SidenavComponent>;
    let service: MsalService;
    let publicClientApplication: PublicClientApplication;
    let pictureService: PictureService;

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                MaterialModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule
            ],
            declarations: [SidenavComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: UserService, useValue: mockUserService },
                { provide: MsalService, useValue: service },
                { provide: MSAL_INSTANCE, useValue: publicClientApplication },
                { provide: PictureService, useValue: pictureService },
                AppConfigService,
                { provide: APP_CONFIGURATION, useValue: mockConfiguration },
                { provide: RebarAuthService, useValue: new MockRebarAuthService() }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
        service = TestBed.inject(MsalService);
        publicClientApplication = TestBed.inject(MSAL_INSTANCE) as unknown as PublicClientApplication;
    }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a tu pictureService debes crearle un Spy "Espía" para setearle data de observable Mock y que así retorne algo cuando hagas la suscripción.

```
describe('SidenavComponent', () => {
....
// let pictureService: PictureService;
let pictureServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<PictureService>;
...

beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {


    pictureServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('PictureService', ['getPicture']);
    
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            MaterialModule,
            RouterTestingModule,
            HttpClientTestingModule
        ],
        declarations: [SidenavComponent],
        providers: [
            ...
            { 
                provide: PictureService, 
                useValue: pictureServiceSpy 
            },
            ...
        ]
    }).compileComponents();
    
});

beforeEach(() => {
    service = TestBed.inject(MsalService);
    publicClientApplication = TestBed.inject(MSAL_INSTANCE) as unknown as PublicClientApplication;


    const mockResponse = 'data que deberia retornar el observable';
    pictureServiceSpy.getPicture = of(mockResponse);


})


afterAll(() => {
    // aca reseteas los spys que hayas creado, es para evitar errores en otras pruebas 
    //es como el unsuscribe en el ngOndestroy
    pictureServiceSpy = null
  })

});
```

Todo lo que tus métodos realicen en el TS deberán replicarlo en el test, así que si hay algo que debe retorna, o calcular o abrir modal, todo eso debe emularse.

Comment: Funciono! Muchas gracias!